# If statement in react function

Tags: reactjs, if-statement

I have 2 inputs with minimum and maximun number range, and I'm trying to use if statement so if user puts in the minimun input value that is higher from the maximun input, it will reset the input to be equal to the maximum. Why it's not working in the function minRangeInputChange?

```js
class Generator extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
      onView: '0',
      minNum: 0 ,
      maxNum: 100
    } 
  }

  btnClick = () => {
    const { minNum, maxNum } = this.state;
    const min = Math.ceil(minNum);
    const max = Math.floor(maxNum);
    const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return this.setState({ onView : x });
  }

  minRangeInputChange = (event) => {
    const { minNum, maxNum } = this.state;
    if (minNum > maxNum) {
      return this.setState({ minNum: maxNum });
    } else {
      return this.setState({ minNum: event.target.value });
      console.log(minNum);
    }
  }

  maxRangeInputChange = (event) => {
    const { maxNum } = this.state;
    this.setState({ maxNum: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Instructions />
        <Range 
          max={this.state.maxNum} 
          min={this.state.minNum} 
          minChange={this.minRangeInputChange}
          maxChange={this.maxRangeInputChange}
        />
        <Generate currentClick={this.btnClick} />
        <View show={this.state.onView} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Generator;
```

The Range Component:

```js
class Range extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="range">
        <h3>Minimum</h3>
        <input
          type="number" 
          value={this.props.minNum} 
          onChange={this.props.minChange} 
          required
        />
        <h3>Maximum</h3>
        <input
          type="number" 
          value={this.props.maxNum}
          onChange={this.props.maxChange}
          required
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Range;
```

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Also, the console.log after the return is unreachable code.

Comment: When still can put higher numbers in the minimun input.

Comment: One clear problem here is that you are doing things in the wrong order. You are comparing the numbers that are in the state _before_ you update the state with the new value. Please rethink your approach because it is not logically sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function minRangeInputChange, your are checking `minNum` vs `maxNum`, so if `0 > 100 then set minNum to 100`. You want to compare the user value vs the max value, so if `XX > max (let's say 50), then set minNum to max`

You should try this value :

```js
  minRangeInputChange = (event) => {
    const { minNum, maxNum } = this.state;
    if (event.target.value > maxNum) {
      return this.setState({ minNum: maxNum });
    } else {
      return this.setState({ minNum: event.target.value });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and still my minimum input can assign higher values then the maximum input.

Comment: In your Generator component, are the state correctly set (only the slider/range component display a wrong value) or are they wrong too ?

Comment: The state is correctly set. If I do console.log(maxNum); inside maxRangeInputChange function for example, It's will updated the state with the new input and print to the console the last state value (I didn't figure out this thing either).

Comment: Try to change your props in `Range` : `value={this.props.min}` instead of `value={this.props.minNum}` : from `Generator`, you are sending `min={this.state.minNum}` and not `minNum={this.state.minNum}` - May not be the answer, but you need to change this !

Comment: Worked! thanks! now we just left the original problem unsolved :)